# How to find Column with same (some x value) value repeated more than once? Needs to return those rows.

Tags: oracle, plsql, duplicates, rows

There is a table called `contacts` with columns `id, name, address, ph_no` etc.
I need to find out rows with the same `name`, if the rows count is more than 1, show those rows.

For example:
Table: `contacts`

```
id--------name--------address---------ph_no--------
111       apple       U.K             99*******
112       banana      U.S             99*******
123       grape       INDIA           99*******
143       orange      S.AFRICA        99*******
152       grape       KENYA           99*******
```

For the above table I need to get rows with same column `name` data like the below:

```
id--------name--------address---------ph_no--------
123       grape       INDIA           99*******
152       grape       KENYA           99*******
```

I need to get the rows based on the name what I given as argument like below `example` syntax:

```
select * from contacts where name='grape' and it's count(*) >1 return those rows.
```

How can I achieve the solution for above problem.

Comment: what is missing exactly from the answers already given? (what details are u looking for)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As @vc74 suggests analytic functions would work work a lot better here; especially if your data has any volume.

```
select id, name, address, ph_no ...
  from ( select c.*, count(name) over ( partition by name ) as name_ct
           from contacts c )
 where name_ct > 1
       ;
```

**EDIT**

restricting on specific names the table `contacts` should really have an index on `name` and the query would look like this:

```
select id, name, address, ph_no ...
  from ( select c.*, count(name) over ( partition by name ) as name_ct
           from contacts c
          where name = 'grape' )
 where name_ct > 1
       ;
```

Comment: your code is working fine, but I need to pass the 'grape' as an argument in to query.

Comment: @azad you can add a where clause if you want. I'd add restrict on the sub-select and have an index on `name`. It does mean though that if you only have one instance of `where name = 'grape'` your query would return nothing?

Comment: it wasn't working. (wasn't returning rows which contain, that field 'grape' more than once). plz can you check once again!.

Comment: Sorry you were correct, you should partition by name to get the count by name. partitioning by 1 gets the total.

Comment: Hi this was very useful but now I want to do this with two columns, that is other than just this name, i need it with same name and ph_no. Is this possible if i put both these as counts and then add in the where clause with AND?

Comment: That should work @Tom, if you need both counts. If you need a single count over both of those columns change the partition clause.

Comment: I don't actually need the count but need all the records with these two columns having the same value, this method seems to work but am still testing it..taking time since its a large amount of data.

Comment: I had a problem using that method, because when i put two counts in the select and checked them in the where clause as count1>1 and count2>1 the problem i faced (might be due to the data) was it always returned a single row. And single row records were not supposed to be returned. Hence i made a workaround to neglect the single row result if and when there was only one row returned from the select using the row_number() and modifying the query by replacing the count() over by the following : (refer next comment)

Comment: row_number() over ( partition by tab.col1 order by  tab.col1) as count1,
    row_number() over (partition by tab2.col2 order by tab2.col2) as count2 and then using the same where clause as before, now its working fine..

Answer (score 3):

```
select id, name, address, ph_no
from contacts
where name in
(
  select name from contacts
  group by name
  having count(*) > 1
)
```

If you have access to Oracle's analytical functions there might be a more straightforward way

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from contacts c 
where c.name in ( select cc.name 
                  from contacts 
                  group by cc.name 
                  having count(1) > 1 );
```